# HttpErrorResponse angular 7

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am working on an angular 7 application but I encounter a problem with a get request.

Here is the error :

```html
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 302, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:9090/things/", ok: false, …}
error: Array(2)
0: {thingId: 7, thingName: "thingName 1"}
1: {thingId: 9, thingName: "thingName 2"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:9090/things/: 302 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 302
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:9090/things/"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

here is my RoleService.ts :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export default class RoleService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllRoles(): Observable<Array<Role>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Role>>(RoleUrls.allRoles).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getRoles', []))
    )
  }

  handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error); // log to console
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-role',
  templateUrl: './role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./role.component.css']
})
export class RoleComponent implements OnInit {

  roles: Array<Role>;
  constructor(private roleService: RoleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRoles();
  }

  getRoles(): void {
    this.roleService.getAllRoles().subscribe(roles => {
      this.roles = roles
    }, error => {
      console.log(error); // The error is here
    })
  }
}
```

I do not understand where this error comes from while the server sends me the requested data.

Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: 302 is a redirection. `An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL in the header field Location. This is an invitation to the user agent (e.g. a web browser) to make a second, otherwise identical, request to the new URL specified in the location field. The end result is a redirection to the new URL.` Check https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/302-found . It has to be server side issue

Comment: Did you test your API successfully in Postman software?

Comment: Are you sure the url you're using in the API is correct?

Answer (score 0):

An http call always return an observable. Sometimes this create some problems when trying to assign a response to an Array. Try to use an assignment like this.

```
 this.roles = Object.assign([], roles);
```